# How to use async knexfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, async.js, hashicorp-vault

I'm having an issue with knex when trying to export config as an async function.

My knexfile is:

```
async function fetchConfiguration() {
  
  return {
    staging:{
      client: 'mysql',
      connection: {
      host : 'dbIp',
      user : 'user',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'myDatabase'
      }
    }
  }
  
}

module.exports = async () => {
  const configuration = await fetchConfiguration();
  return {
    ...configuration
  }
};
```

and my connection.js is:

```
const knex = require('knex');
const configuration = require('../../knexfile');

var connection = knex(configuration.staging);

module.exports = connection;
```

but when running, I'm getting this error

```
C:\Users\fabio\Documents\Projetos_CVC\uptime\uptime\API\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:22
  if (arguments.length === 0 || (!config.client && !config.dialect)) {
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at Knex (C:\Users\fabio\Documents\Projetos_CVC\uptime\uptime\API\node_modules\knex\lib\knex.js:22:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabio\Documents\Projetos_CVC\uptime\uptime\API\src\database\connection.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fabio\Documents\Projetos_CVC\uptime\uptime\API\src\controllers\CheckController.js:1:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
```

Soon I ll need to use vault and consul in this project, so not using async creation is complicated.
I appreciate any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your config is async, you need to wait to it.

That means that in order to configure the connection, your code should be async all the way.

It should look something like:

```js
// dbConfig.js
async function fetchConfiguration() {
  
  return {
    staging:{
      client: 'mysql',
      connection: {
      host : 'dbIp',
      user : 'user',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'myDatabase'
      }
    }
  }
  
}

module.exports = async () => {
  const configuration = await fetchConfiguration();
  return {
    ...configuration
  }
};
```

```js
// db.js
const knex = require('knex');
const configuration = require('../../dbConfig');

const config = await configuration();
// --------------^ you are exporting an async function, it must be awaited

const connection = knex(config.staging);
module.exports = connection;
```

ps, [top level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) is not supported by all node versions, check if yours is supports it. if not, you can wrap the code with iffe as it was described in the link.